# Get authentication from login and use it in a javascript page

Tags: javascript, java, authentication

I need to get the authentication saved from the login and use it in a javascript page.

Pratically, I need to make this authentication dynamic and not static taking it from a login.

`const auth = 'Basic <Authentication Token Here>';`

i am coding in java
this is my login:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService; 
    
    @Bean
    protected BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    };
    
    @Autowired
    private void initialize(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder());
    }
    
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class HttpRestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            
            LOG.info("########## Http rest security configured");
        }
    }
    
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class HttpSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
        @Bean
        public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
            return new SessionRegistryImpl();
        }
        
        @Bean
        public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
            return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
        }
        
        private SessionInformationExpiredStrategy expiredSessionStrategy() {
            return new SessionInformationExpiredStrategy() {
                @Override
                public void onExpiredSessionDetected(SessionInformationExpiredEvent event) throws IOException {
                    event.getRequest().getSession(false).invalidate();
                    event.getResponse().sendRedirect("/smug/login/form?invalid");
                }
            };
        }
        
        private SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
            return new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
                    
                    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
                    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ nell'authentication login c'è: " + authentication.getName());
                    request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(600);
                    LOG.debug("########## Session created: "+ request.getSession().getId());
                    
                }
            };
        }
        
        private LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
            return new LogoutSuccessHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

                    HttpSession session =  request.getSession(false);
                    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);
                    response.sendRedirect("/smug/login/form?logout");
                    
                }
                
            };
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin(formLogin->
                    formLogin
                        .loginPage("/login/form")
                        .permitAll()
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                        .usernameParameter("username")
                        .passwordParameter("password")
                        .successHandler(this.loginSuccessHandler())
                        .failureUrl("/login/form?error"))
                .logout(logout ->
                    logout
                        .logoutUrl("/login/form")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(false)
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login/form?logout")
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(this.logoutSuccessHandler())
                        .clearAuthentication(true))
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/login/form?forbidden")
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/login/form?invalid")
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .expiredSessionStrategy(this.expiredSessionStrategy())
                    .sessionRegistry(this.sessionRegistry());
            
            LOG.info("########## Http security configured");
        }
    }
}
```

and i have a js with this constant auth. i need to get the authorization from here that contains the details i needed and pass them to the js. in that way i can add at my log in the db who made the operation

this is the js:

```
const csrfParameter = $("meta[name='_csrf_parameter']").attr("content");
const csrfHeader = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
const csrfToken = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
//const auth=$('#header').val();
const auth = 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fa-plus").each(function(index){
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            $('.qta').eq(index).text(parseInt($('.qta').eq(index).text()) + 1);
            var idRigaNota=$('.id').eq(index).text();
            var idArt=$('.idArt').eq(index).text();
            var idNota=$('#idNota').val();
            var quantitaArticolo=$('.qta').eq(index).text();
            var JsonNota;
            var JsonArticolo;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:"http://localhost:8080/smug/api/articolo/"+idArt,
                async:false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                  alert("errore articolo "+idArt);
                },
                success: function(data){
                    JsonArticolo=data;
                },
            }); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:"http://localhost:8080/smug/api/nota/"+idNota,
                async:false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                  alert("errore nota "+idNota);
                },
                success: function(data){
                    JsonNota=data;
                },
            });
            var JsonRigaNota ={
                    "idRigaNota": idRigaNota,
                    "notaDiCarico": JsonNota,
                    "articolo": JsonArticolo,
                    "quantitaArticolo": quantitaArticolo
                };  
            var headers = {};
            headers[csrfHeader] = csrfToken;
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                headers: headers,
                url:"http://localhost:8080/smug/api/riga/update",
                data:JSON.stringify(JsonRigaNota),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    alert("errore riga nota");
                },
                success: function(){
                    location.reload();
//                  $('#table').load(document.URL+' table');
                },
            });
        }); 
    });
});
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fa-minus").each(function(index){
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            $('.qta').eq(index).text(parseInt($('.qta').eq(index).text()) - 1);
            var idRigaNota=$('.id').eq(index).text();
            var idArt=$('.idArt').eq(index).text();
            var idNota=$('#idNota').val();
            var quantitaArticolo=$('.qta').eq(index).text();
            var JsonNota;
            var JsonArticolo;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:"http://localhost:8080/smug/api/articolo/"+idArt,
                async:false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                },
                success: function(data){
                    JsonArticolo=data;
                },
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:"http://localhost:8080/smug/api/nota/"+idNota,
                async:false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                },
                success: function(data){
                    JsonNota=data;
                },
            });
            var JsonRigaNota ={
                    "idRigaNota": idRigaNota,
                    "notaDiCarico": JsonNota,
                    "articolo": JsonArticolo,
                    "quantitaArticolo": quantitaArticolo
                }; 
            var headers = {};
            headers[csrfHeader] = csrfToken;
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                headers: headers,
                url:"http://localhost:8080/smug/api/riga/update",
                data:JSON.stringify(JsonRigaNota),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                },
                success: function(){
                    location.reload();
                },
            });
            
        }); 
    });
});
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fa-trash-alt").each(function(index){
        $(this).on("click", function(){
          if(confirm("Vuoi eliminare: "+$('.desArt').eq(index).text()+"?")){
             var idRigaNota=$('.id').eq(index).text();
             var headers = {};
             headers[csrfHeader] = csrfToken;
               $.ajax({
                 type: "DELETE",
                 headers: headers,
                   url:"http://localhost:8080/smug/api/riga/delete/"+idRigaNota,
                   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
                    },
                   error: function(e) {
                      console.log(e);
                    },
                    success: function(){
                      location.reload();
                    },
               });
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: You should have an API endpoint to generate auth token for you

Comment: my login is already done i am using this js page only to not refresh the entire page, i need to put the right name for the authentication to write a log of operations in the db

Comment: you need to decode token, then extract username, you can store at LocalStorage browser, mostly we set HTTP request header Authentcation with the Bearer or basic token

Comment: Please try to explain which parts of your code are java and which are javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `localstorage` of browser `window` object for setting string value,

```
const auth = 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=';

window.localStorage.setItem("AuthKey", auth);// set
window.localStorage.getItem("AuthKey");//get
```

to make it dynamic, you can `setItem` whenever you want, it will update storage value, does this answers your question?

Comment: Unfortunatly no, but i think is because of my lack of experience. this js page, is only made to not refresh the entire page, but my login is made in java. i need to get informations i already had saved in authentication. now other persons had set this static auth, just to try. but now i need to write in the db the log of who made the changes of the page. and every other change is going good, exept for this one because this constant overwrite the one i have in the login authentication. i know i am not explaining it well.